# CakePHP Absolute Image URLs

Tags: url, cakephp

I wish to use the `$html->image(...)` helper function in CakePHP to output images, but I need it to produce an `img` tag using an absolute rather than relative URL (the resulting HTML will be downloaded and emailed round in a company newsletter). Is this possible?

It's not documented, but I notice from looking at the source code that the `image` function can take an array as its first argument. It's not entirely clear to me how to get this working though - a naive attempt to do it this way produces image URLs relative to the current page rather than within the `webroot/img` folder.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In CakePHP 1.x the method is:

```
$this->Html->image($this->Html->url('/path_to_image/image.png',true));
```

In CakePHP 2.x the method is:

```
$this->Html->image('/path_to_image/image.png', array('fullBase' => true));
```

Comment: @Jleagle I updated my answer to specify the correct way in each version. (1.3 was the current version when I originally posted this answer)

Answer (score 9):

The correct way to do this is in CakePHP 2.x:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->image("logo.png", array('fullBase' => true));
```

Code pulled direct from the cookbook:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html

Answer (score 1):

`$html->image('http://example.com/path_to_image/image.png');` should do the trick.

Comment: That should be CakePHP's motto :)

Comment: What if I move my site to be on example2.com?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
$html->image('http://[domain]/[path]/[image]')
```

Answer (score 0):

**With Link Image:-**

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('logo.png',array('alt'=>'Logo')),'/', array('fullBase'=>true)); ?>
```

**Only Images Display :-**

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('logo.png',array('alt'=>'Logo')),'/', array('fullBase'=>true); ?>
```

Answer (score -4):

<img src="http://example.com/path_to_image/image.png" alt="" />

sometimes it's better to keep the simplest way

Comment: In Cake's case, it is expressly not.